# How to store data from When statement in Drools?

Tags: java, drools

I need the data that caused the rule to be fired from the "When" section in the "Then" section of the rule. For instance, if I wanted to make note of all bad apples in a store if there were more than 50, this is how I'm doing it.

```
Rule "Detect Bad Apples"
  When
    s : Store( numberOfBadApples() > 50 )
  Then
    // Print out a list of the bad apples
```

To make it a little more complicated I have multiple rules that will overwrite. Otherwise, I would store the data into a variable in the Store class.

Is there a better way to do this? I've been reading through the [Drools 6.2 Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR2/drools-docs/html/), but I'm still confused.

---EDIT----

The Store Class in Java would look like:

```
public class Store {
  private ArrayList<Apple> appleList;
  // The appleList would be filled in another method

  public int numberOfBadApples() {
    int badAppleCount = 0;

    for (Apple apple : appleList) {
      if (apple.isBad()) {
        badAppleCount++;
      }
    }

    return badAppleCount;      
  }
}
```

So in the "Then" statement in Drools, I want to return a list of the apples (the bad ones, in this case) that caused the rule to be fired.

Comment: Please add the declarations of Store and numberOfBadApples so that one can see what you mean by a "list of bad apples". Surely, there is a list in the Store? How?

Comment: You can access the `Store` via the variable `s`, so how about `s.getBadApples()`?